# How to Calculate the Sum of Multiple Tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I have 3 Tables Namely: Inventory,ConsumedProducts, DamagedProducts

Inventory:

```
|ID|TransactionDate     |Item             |Unit|Quantity|
---------------------------------------------------------
|1 |2019-07-10 12:23:51 |Plastic Cup 22oz |Pc  |200     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|2 |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Plastic Cup 16oz |Pc  |100     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|3 |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Plastic Cup 22oz |Pc  |100     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|4 |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Lemon            |Pc  |100     |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

ConsumedProducts:

```
|ID|TID|TransactionDate     |Item           |Unit|Quantity|
---------------------------------------------------------

|1 |1  |2019-07-10 12:23:51 |Plastic Cup 22oz |Pc  |1     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|2 |1  |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Lemon            |Pc  |1     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|3 |2  |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Plastic Cup 16oz |Pc  |1     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|4 |2  |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Lemon            |Pc  |1     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|5 |3  |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Plastic Cup 16oz |Pc  |1     |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

DamagedProducts:

```
|ID|TransactionDate     |Item             |Unit|Quantity|
---------------------------------------------------------
|1 |2019-07-10 12:23:51 |Plastic Cup 22oz |Pc  |10      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|2 |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Plastic Cup 16oz |Pc  |10      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|3 |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Plastic Cup 22oz |Pc  |5       |
---------------------------------------------------------
|4 |2019-07-10 01:23:51 |Lemon            |Pc  |6       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make an Output like This?

Inventory:

```
|ID|Item             |Inv Bal|Consumed Prod|Dmgd Prod|Actual Balance
---------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Plastic Cup 22oz |300    |    1        |15       |284
---------------------------------------------------------
|2 |Plastic Cup 16oz |100    |    2        |10       |88
---------------------------------------------------------
|3 |Lemon            |100    |    2        |6        |92
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried other approach but it does't give me the desire result. I, just an aspiring programmer so any help would be very much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
  I.ID, I.Item, IFNULL(SUM(I.Quantity),0), 
  IFNULL(SUM(C.Quantity),0), IFNULL(SUM(D.Quantity),0), 
  IFNULL((IFNULL(SUM(I.Quantity),0) - (IFNULL(SUM(C.Quantity),0) + 
  IFNULL(SUM(D.Quantity),0))),0) AS NEW_BAL 
From 
 Inventory I 
 Left OUTER Join ConsumedProducts C 
 ON I.Item = C.Item 
 LEFT Outer Join DamagedProducts D 
 ON D.Item = I.Item 
GROUP BY I.Item, C.Item, D.Item
```

The Output is multiplied by the results of the other table.

Comment: Can you please tell me the unique ids for every item?

Comment: You should be joining on `ID` and not `Item`

Comment: Thank you for a very fast response I will try what you had suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join to the subquery as below:

```
SELECT 
  I.ID, I.Item, SUM(I.Quantity) as `Inv Bal`,
  D.Quantity as damagedQTY,
  C.Quantity as ConsumedQTY,
  SUM(I.Quantity) + D.Quantity -C.Quantity as NEWBALANCE  
From 
 Inventory I 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 ( select item,SUM(Quantity) as Quantity from DamagedProducts group by item) D on I.item=D.item
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (select item,SUM(Quantity) as Quantity from ConsumedProducts group by tID) C on I.item=C.item
GROUP BY I.Item
```

Comment: Thank you sel for the answer. this really work for me. I upvoted but I dunno why it shows -1

Comment: @MattPedrosa no problem. Good to hear that it works.

Comment: Is there anyway I can add another Column before the INV_BAL which would calculate the sum of the Balance before the Current Date?

Comment: Could you please provide some example data for better understanding of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your Problem (Might not be an optimized query I think):

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
(@row_number := @row_number+1) ID
,I.ITEM
,I.Quantity INV_BAL
,CP.Quantity CONSUMED_PROD
,DP.Quantity DMGD_PROD
,I.Quantity - CP.Quantity - DP.Quantity AS NEW_BAL 
FROM
(SELECT ITEM, SUM(QUANTITY) QUANTITY FROM Inventory GROUP BY ITEM) I
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ITEM, SUM(QUANTITY) QUANTITY FROM ConsumedProducts GROUP BY ITEM) CP
ON I.ITEM = CP.ITEM
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ITEM, SUM(QUANTITY) QUANTITY FROM DamagedProducts GROUP BY ITEM) DP
ON I.ITEM = DP.ITEM
ORDER BY I.ITEM DESC
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ID  ITEM                INV_BAL CONSUMED_PROD   DMGD_PROD   NEW_BAL
1   Plastic Cup 22oz    300     1               15          284
2   Plastic Cup 16oz    100     2               10           88
3   Lemon               100     2                6           92
```

**Demo Link to the solution:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/684a8b/11

Comment: This works too thank you very much sir Ninshant Gupta. Faith in humanity is still really there

Comment: @MattPedrosa Welcome Sir, My name is Nishant not Ninshant.

Comment: I'm so sorry sir. I never meant any disrespect... Thank you again

Comment: Is there anyway I can add another Column before the INV_BAL which would calculate the sum of the Balance before the Current Date?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more about your prob?

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. the question has been answered on a separate post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139266/complex-multiple-table-inventory-sql-query/57139487#57139487