# Complex Multiple Table Inventory SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sum, multiple-tables

I have 3 Tables: Assuming "2019-07-19" is the (Current Date)

1.Inventory:

```
___________________________________________________
|ID| TransactionDate | ItemID | ItemName |Quantity|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|1 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |100     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|2 |2019-07-19       | 2      |Sugar     |100     | 
+-------------------------------------------------+
|3 |2019-07-19       | 2      |Sugar     |100     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|4 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |100     |
+-------------------------------------------------+ 
|5 |2019-07-19       | 1      |Lemon     |100     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|6 |2019-07-18       | 2      |Sugar     |100     |
+-------------------------------------------------+ 
|7 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |100     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

2.ConsumedItems:

```
___________________________________________________ 
|ID| TransactionDate | ItemID | ItemName |Quantity|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|1 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|2 |2019-07-19       | 2      |Sugar     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|3 |2019-07-19       | 2      |Sugar     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|4 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|5 |2019-07-19       | 1      |Lemon     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|6 |2019-07-18       | 2      |Sugar     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|7 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

3.DamagedItems:

```
___________________________________________________  
|ID| TransactionDate | ItemID | ItemName |Quantity|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|1 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|2 |2019-07-19       | 2      |Sugar     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|3 |2019-07-19       | 2      |Sugar     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|4 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+  
|5 |2019-07-19       | 1      |Lemon     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|6 |2019-07-18       | 2      |Sugar     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|7 |2019-07-18       | 1      |Lemon     |10      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I get this Output?

1. PrevBalance=[Sum Of All Previous Inventories] - ([Sum of all Previous Damaged] + [Sum Of All Consumed])
2. DmgToday=[Sum of all Current Damaged]
3. CnsmdToday=[Sum of all Current Consumed]
4. DlvrdToday=[Sum of all Items in Inventory Today]

---

```
| ItemID | ItemName |PrevBalance|DlvrdToday|DmgToday|CnsmdToday|CurrentBal
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1       |Lemon     | 240       |100       |10      |10        |320      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2       |Sugar     | 80        |200       |20      |20        |240      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Working Code:

```
select Inventory.ItemID, Inventory.ItemName,  
sum(case when Inventory.TransactionDate < CURDATE() then Inventory.Quantity 
else 0 end)-sum(case when ConsumedItems.TransactionDate <CURDATE() then 
ConsumedItems.Quantity else 0 end)-sum(case when 
DamagedItems.TransactionDate<CURDATE() then DamagedItems.Quantity else 0 end) as 'PrevBalance',

sum(case when Inventory.TransactionDate=CURDATE() then Inventory.Quantity else 0 end) as 'DeliveredToday',

sum(case when DamagedItems.TransactionDate=CURDATE() then DamagedItems.Quantity else 0 end) as 'DamagedToday',

sum(case when ConsumedItems.TransactionDate=CURDATE() then ConsumedItems.Quantity else 0 end) as 'ConsumedToday',

sum(case when Inventory.TransactionDate < CURDATE() then Inventory.Quantity else 0 end)-
sum(case when ConsumedItems.TransactionDate <CURDATE() then ConsumedItems.Quantity else 0 end)-
sum(case when DamagedItems.TransactionDate<CURDATE() then DamagedItems.Quantity else 0 end)-
sum(case when ConsumedItems.TransactionDate=CURDATE() then ConsumedItems.Quantity else 0 end)-
sum(case when DamagedItems.TransactionDate=CURDATE() then DamagedItems.Quantity else 0 end)+
sum(case when Inventory.TransactionDate=CURDATE() then Inventory.Quantity else 0 end) as 'Total Balance' 

from Inventory 
join ConsumedItems on ConsumedItems.ID = Inventory.ID 
join DamagedItems on DamagedItems.ID = Inventory.ID
group by  Inventory.ItemID, Inventory.ItemName`
```

Comment: what have you done so far? And add create table create script and sample data so that someone can help you by testing it locally.

Comment: Hint: Use `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query

```
select Inventory.ItemID, Inventory.ItemName, 
sum(case when Inventory.TransactionDate<currentdate() then Inventory.Quantity else 0 end)+sum(case when ConsumedItems.TransactionDate<currentdate() then ConsumedItems.Quantity else 0 end)-sum(case when DamagedItems.TransactionDate<currentdate() then DamagedItems.Quantity else 0 end) as 'PrevBalance',
sum(case when DamagedItems.TransactionDate=currentdate() then DamagedItems.Quantity else 0 end) as 'DamagedToday',
sum(case when ConsumedItems.TransactionDate=currentdate() then ConsumedItems.Quantity else 0 end) as 'ConsumedToday', 
sum(case when ConsumedItems.TransactionDate=currentdate() then ConsumedItems.Quantity else 0 end)+sum(case when DamagedItems.TransactionDate=currentdate() then DamagedItems.Quantity else 0 end)+sum(case when Inventory.TransactionDate=currentdate() then Inventory.Quantity else 0 end) as 'DeliveredToday' 
from Inventory 
join ConsumedItems on ConsumedItems.ID = Inventory.ID 
join DamagedItems on DamagedItems.ID = Inventory.ID
group by  Inventory.ItemID, Inventory.ItemName
```